# Is there a maximum time limit to accept an answer?

Tags: support, accepted-answer

I can see Q/A about the minimum time to accept answers, ie. 15 minutes (or 2 days for self-answers).

But what is the *maximum* time limit to accept an answer?

Comment: There's no upper limit. Answers can be accepted any time after the minimum waiting period has elapsed.

Comment: Furthermore, you can change the accepted answer later (unlimited amount of times I believe)

Comment: From MSE's [How does accepting an answer work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/571958): *"You may change which answer is accepted, or simply un-accept the answer, __at any time__."* Which kinda implicitly says that you can simply accept at any time (assuming the minimum requirement has passed...)

Comment: My [personal record](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1398789) is having an answer of mine marked as accepted 8 years and 6 months after posting it.

Comment: The longest delay between answer and accept currently stands at 12.5 years (4572 days); [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53012/algorithm-to-decide-if-digital-audio-data-is-clipping/176110#176110) was posted not long after Stack Overflow first started, and was marked accepted last week.

Comment: On a related note, there's no time limit on getting unaccepted either. A few days ago, a new answer appeared on a question I answered in 2014. The OP decided to unaccept my answer and accept the new one. (FWIW, I also upvoted the new answer).

Comment: @Martijn Pieters: Nice, yours is just a little over [mine](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/695498/answers-that-took-way-too-long-to-accept-single-user?UserId=106224) (about 8 years and 2 months). [Here's](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/695493/answers-that-took-way-too-long-to-accept-all-users?MinYears=10) a query to find the current site-wide record (it's 4572 days, not 4752).

Comment: There *is* an end to when an answer can be accepted. It's defined as `Math.min(stack_overflow_end_of_life, universe_end_of_life)`. That's just the max bound. Usually acceptance is further restricted by the lifetime of the user. Unless, they are immortal, Jon Skeet, or a different person logs into the account.

Comment: @BoltClock: I had [created a similar query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1398791), just can't type numbers for toffee.. I *can* however, edit my comment and make it look like I never got that wrong!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There is no limit to the maximum time to accept an answer (other than the heat-death of the universe).

Comment: It's somewhat less than that given that dead people can't type, so each question can only be accepted within the lifetime of the question's OP.

Comment: I was hoping to be done here in 6 to 8 weeks, now you tell me I have to wait for some heat-death? Bummer ....

Comment: @RobertLongson what if I bequeathed my account to my descendants?

Comment: @MartijnPieters interesting hypothetical... is that not against the rules?

Comment: @Gimby What rule would it be against?